# Using find to pass multiple files to awk and redirect result into one output file

Tags: shell, awk, find, xargs

I have an awk script that processes files passed in. It runs on one input file and redirects into one output file...

```
awk -f solar.awk ./PerformanceData_2023-08-02_02-02-17/tmp_YdayData.txt > output.txt
```

... however, passing multiple files does not work.

For example passing in two files like so:

```
awk -f solar.awk ./PerformanceData_2023-08-02_02-02-17/tmp_YdayData.txt ./PerformanceData_2023-08-01_02-02-17/tmp_YdayData.txt
```

... only processes the first file (not the second): No idea why.

However, what I'd like to ultimately achieve is finding files in sub directories and run the awk command against it, collecting the results in one output file.

```
find . -type f -name 'tmp_YdayData.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -t awk -f solar.awk >> output.txt
```

While this finds the relevant files (if I run the command portion before the pipe) the full command line, however, it only processes the first file.

```
find . -type f -name 'tmp_YdayData.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -t awk -f /home/maxg/Workspaces/awk/solar/solar.awk
awk -f /home/maxg/Workspaces/awk/solar/solar.awk ./PerformanceData_2023-08-01_02-02-17/tmp_YdayData.txt ./PerformanceData_2023-08-02_02-02-17/tmp_YdayData.txt ./PerformanceData_2023-08-03_02-02-17/tmp_YdayData.txt ./PerformanceData_2023-08-04_02-02-18/tmp_YdayData.txt ./PerformanceData_2023-08-05_02-02-37/tmp_YdayData.txt ./PerformanceData_2023-08-06_02-02-18/tmp_YdayData.txt
```

01/08/2023, 66.03, 25.59, 36.25, 12.81,  0.41, 17.30,  -0.10,  22.2, 100.0,   10:55

What am I doing wrong?

I have not provided the awk script, as reducing its content to `print $0` generates the same result.

I have since posted the solution, as my command line arguments where incorrect.

Comment: Does running your `awk` command on each file manually works?

Comment: yes (see first example)

Comment: Your `awk` script is maybe designed to process only one file. As you don't show it we cannot really help.

Comment: MVCE required: minimal, complete, verifiable example (including not only code but sample input and output, as applicable) that anyone can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add `-n1` to your `xargs` to limit arguments to one per spawn: `-n, --max-args=MAX-ARGS      use at most MAX-ARGS arguments per command line`

Answer (score 1):

Well, after lots of fiddling, the following command does what I want:

```
find . -type f -name 'tmp_YdayData.txt' -exec awk -f solar.awk {} >> output.txt\;
```

I changed the command line from `xargs` to `exec`.